# Decompiling, modifying and compiling a flash object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have never worked with flash (SWF) before but I am in a situation where I need to modify an old flash object used internally on a site. The problem is that the flash object contains a year picker that stops with 2021 which is a problem now.

The source code is not available anymore (it's nearly 10 years old) but I have managed to decompile it using an online service and thus obtaining the source. I also found the year picker's definition, which goes like this:

```
        ...
        {
            label:"2020",
            data:"2020"
        }, {
            label:"2021",
            data:"2021"
        }];
```

So the actual change is easy enough, but how do I proceed from here?

I have no idea how to compile flash, and there is no make file etc which I guess is normally used.

How do I compile the flash object again from the modified source?

*Note: For various reasons it is not an option to simply skip the flash object and building the same functionality using HTML.*

Comment: Depends what kind of project it is. It could be AS2 FLA project with AS2 classes, or AS3 FLA project with AS3 classes - in both cases you will need Flash IDE (the current one is called **Adobe Animate CC**, the previous one is **Adobe Flash Professional CS6**). If it is a pure AS3 project, then you are in luck and you can re-build it with a free tool, like **FlashDevelop** + **Flex SDK**. If it was a Flex project - not so sure. You can also try this: https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/features/ - it seems you can modify SWFs without actually decompiling them.

Comment: Thanks. How do I see what  kind of project it is? The decompiler tool looks interesting, I will check that out.

Comment: Weeeell, if you decompiled it and it produced non-empty FLA file (you open it with Flash IDE to learn if it is non-empty), then AS2 classes and AS2 code look a bit different than AS3 classes (cannot tell you how exactly, because last time I worked with AS2 classes was about 10 years ago).

Comment: When exporting to FLA I got a lot of non-empty FLA files but I have no idea which AS version it is. Anyway, using the decompiler I was able to modify the P Code to add a new year range. I tried editing the high level code but when saving it complained about a missing namespace. Luckily, the P code was very simple for this task. If you could add your comment as an answer, I could mark it as accepted. If you don't care, I will just answer it myself.

Comment: It's fine as long as it worked out : )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from Organis, this is what I did.

1. I downloaded the [Free Flash Decompiler](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/) and opened the SWF file. This gave me a treeview of objects and code modules to the left.
2. I searched for "2021" since this was the last year in the dropdown.
3. Found the relevant section which looked like this:

   ```
    ...
    {
      "label":"2020",
      "data":"2020"
    },{
      "label":"2021",
      "data":"2021"
    }];
   ```
4. I tried editing the source code, but it didn't work. Got a namespace error.
5. Instead I edited the P Code in the right pane. It looked like this:

   ```
   pushstring "label"
   pushstring "2022"
   pushstring "data"
   pushstring "2022"
   newobject 2
   ...
   newarray <number of years>
   ```
6. Note that array length had to be adjusted to the total numbers of years in the range
7. Furthermore I had to increase the stack size etc because the Flash object crashed when loaded. I increased all these values a little by trial-and-error.

   ```
   body
   maxstack 17
   localcount 3
   initscopedepth 15
   maxscopedepth 17
   ```

Hope it helps somebody in a similar situation.